# Generating postgresql user password

Tags: python, postgresql

I tried to generate password for `postgres` using `hashlib` from Python.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5("psql123").hexdigest()
2636d1ddc54901f98d011ffe050c0eb7
```

But postgresql requires `md5` prefix, so then

```
sudo -u postgres psql
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'md52636d1ddc54901f98d011ffe050c0eb7';
```

However, authentication would fail if I use `psql123` as password.

If I use `passlib`, I am fine. See http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.postgres_md5.html

Doing the following using `psql123` as password is okay.

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'md556074e7318bd4cee558faab0678a2fad';
```

I don't understand what the warning in `passlib` want to say. Is it okay to use this hash for `postgres` user?  Also, where in the doc does it say `username` has to be part of the input?

I assume this is why `postgres` can't understand the result from `hashlib`. As a LDAP user, I can generate a password in the shell. Does postgres has a built-in command to do that? Does `psycopg2` has that? It looks like it doesn't.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Postgres' password  hash is very close to what you did, it just needs the  username to be included as follows:

```
 pghash = "md5" + hashlib.md5(password + username).hexdigest()
```

AFAIK, the postgres docs don't really document this hash format at all, and seem to assume admins will rarely deal with these hashes directly :( There are no builtin methods for generating these hashes that I know of. If the password provided to the `ALTER USER` command doesn't conform to the postgres hash format, it assumes the password hasn't been hashed, and takes care of that internally - per the docs for [CREATE ROLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrole.html)'s ENCRYPTED keyword. (IMHO this is a flawed behavior, because if a hash depends on the username, it means hashes can't be copied and pasted between different accounts, break when the account is renamed, and (guessing entropy wise) only has ~6 bits of effective salt).

The warning at the top of passlib's documentation for the hash could probably be clearer. It was meant to warn people browsing through the passlib documentation that 1) this hash was horribly insecure, 2) that they shouldn't adopt it for use in their own applications, and 3) that it was only fit for the purpose of working with postgres user accounts, since it's the strongest (and only) hash format postgres supports for it's own accounts.

(If you're trying to use postgres to hash passwords for your own application's user accounts, I'd strongly second Clodoaldo's recommendation to use bcrypt by way of the pgcrypto extension).

Comment: Thanks so much. I upvote both of you but since you answered all my concerns, I will check you. But I thank both of you. NO, the hash is just for `postgres` user account, not app user account. That kind of hash reminds me of the two naive MAC construction which leads to extension/length attack, ie.

Answer (score 5):

```
alter user postgres ENCRYPTED password 'psql123';
```

For other uses use the [`pgcrypto`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgcrypto.html) module.

```
create table "user" (name text, password_hash text);

insert into "user" (name, password_hash) values
('u1', crypt('psql123', gen_salt('bf')));

select * from "user";
 name |                        password_hash                         
------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 u1   | $2a$06$SeH4u4aRtT2Zr39er4eSiONT/0IBQHYMbQXn2RauPJKCYdNX1.58G

select name, password_hash = crypt('psql123', password_hash)
from "user"
;
 name | ?column? 
------+----------
 u1   | t
```

Install it as super user logged in the target database:

```
create extension pgcrypto;
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I will check out pgcrypto later. Very useful information.