# Postgres: MD5 Password / Plain password

Tags: postgresql, md5, role

I'm trying to understand how role passwords are supposed to operate in Postgres.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html says for ENCRYPTED / UNENCRYPTED

> If the presented password string is already in MD5-encrypted format, then it is stored encrypted as-is,

So my unencrypted password is: MyPassword .

The MD5 hash of "MyPassword" is 48503dfd58720bd5ff35c102065a52d7

If I do

```
-- See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterrole.html
ALTER ROLE "MeOhMy"
LOGIN
PASSWORD '48503dfd58720bd5ff35c102065a52d7'
;
```

And then attempt to use "MyPassword" when doing

```
  sudo -u postgres psql meohmy -h 127.0.0.1 -d meohmy_development
```

I, of course, first get prompted for my sudo password and then I get prompted by Postgres "Password for meohmy"

If I enter MyPassword I get

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ralph@dos32.com"
```

If I enter, instead, 48503dfd58720bd5ff35c102065a52d7 then I can sign in.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: MD5 is not encryption as hash function are not encryption, they are one-way non-reversible methods. Encryption assumes decryption, that with the correct key encrypted data can be returned to it's us un-encrypted state.

Comment: MD5 is not a secure or acceptable password verifier. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: While you are absolutely correct in both your comments, there are two considerations:
1) I am limited to the facilities Postgres is giving me.
2) The data I am protecting isn't that valuable so spending time to protect it with the highest grade of security just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 32):

To create an md5 password for PostgreSQL, the formula is:

```
"md5" + md5(password + username)
```

Here are 3 ways you can create one, where the username is "admin" and the password is "password123"...

**Linux:**

```
# echo -n "md5"; echo -n "password123admin" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
md53f84a3c26198d9b94054ca7a3839366d
```

NOTE:  The -n is critical to avoid including the newline character in your hash!

**MacOS:**

```
➜ echo -n "md5"; md5 -qs "password123admin"                                                                                                                                                                                   
md53f84a3c26198d9b94054ca7a3839366d
```

**Python 2:**

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> print("md5" + hashlib.md5("password123" + "admin").hexdigest())
md53f84a3c26198d9b94054ca7a3839366d
```

**Python 3:**

as above, but use binary strings

```
print("md5" + hashlib.md5(b"password123" + b"admin").hexdigest())
```

Comment: In the Linux example I think its better to use single quotes instead of double quotes. For example, if the password has the special character `$`, the double quotes would interpret it as a variable. Like `echo -n "password$123admin"` vs `echo -n 'password$123admin'`.
[See other interesting behaviors here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/8185511).

Answer (score 3):

Postgresql hashed passwords have `md5` prefix:

```
md548503dfd58720bd5ff35c102065a52d7
```

Comment: Where is this documented!!?! All I have found is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918763/generating-postgresql-user-password

Comment: @RalphShnelvar https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-authid.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Postgres11 on GCP Cloud SQL. Gitlab version gitlab-ee 13.3.4 Omnibus install

```
# gitlab-ctl pg-password-md5 gitlab_user
Enter password:
Confirm password:
```

and

```
# echo -n <password for gitlab_user>gitlab_user | md5sum
```

are equivalent.

Note: My db user is `gitlab_user`

Answer (score -1):

The answer provided by @zerkms is partially correct. It led me to the right answer.

The answer provided in [Generating postgresql user password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918763/generating-postgresql-user-password) is the answer that works for me.

Comment: Just a link is insufficient, it does not fully help future readers and may become invalid.

Comment: Ok ... for future readers the article I pointed at says:

    `pghash = "md5" + hashlib.md5(password + username).hexdigest()`